# C++ passing a struct to a function to access a nested struct

Tags: c++, function, struct

I have some data organised in nested structs and am trying to access it. There are 4 layers and then the final struct always has 2 variables; `val` and `addr`:

```
struct Flash{
  struct Settings{
    struct UnderVoltage{
      struct Threshold{
        int16_t val = 2850;
        uint16_t addr = 0x4481;
      } Threshold;
      struct Delay{
        uint8_t val = 2;
        uint16_t addr = 0x4483;
      } Delay;
      struct Recovery{
        int16_t val = 2900;
        uint16_t addr = 0x4484;
      } Recovery;
    } UnderVoltage;
  } Settings;
} Flash;
```

I want to be able have a function along the lines of

```
void writeThreshold(){

  writeFlash( Flash.Settings.UnderVoltage.Threshold );

}
```

that then calls a function like

```
void writeFlash( struct dataParam ){

  byte addr1 = dataParam.addr & 0xFF;
  byte addr2 = ( dataParam.addr >> 8 ) & 0xFF;

  uint8_t byteLen = sizeof( dataParam.val );
  byte valBytes[ byteLen ];
  for( int i = 0; i < byteLen; i++ ){
    valBytes[ i ] = dataParam.val >> ( i * 8 );
  }

}
```

So is there a way to send the struct nesting to a function so that function can access the variables within it?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the same name for the members as for the types. In C++, structs don't have their own namespace.

Comment: `byte valBytes[ byteLen ];` isn't C++. `byteLen` needs to be marked `constexpr` or `const`

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void writeFlash(const T& dataParam){
// ... as before
```

Comment: (Although preferably marking `byteLen` as `constexpr` so that we're not relying on VLAs...)

Comment: Thanks. When I call `writeFlash( Flash.Settings.OverVoltage.Threshold );` I get an error that `Flash` was not declared in this scope

Comment: OK, all seems good. I deleted the `Flash` member from where I declare the structs. Now I create a member local to the `writeThreshold()` function, before calling the `writeFlash()` function. Thanks a lot